# Using complex exponential to show the indefinite integration of sin(x)sinh(x) dx

Tags: calculus

Use the complex exponential to evaluate the indefinite integral of 
$\sin x \sinh x$.

Express your answer in terms of trigonometric and/or hyperbolic functions

The attached photo is what I have tried so far
[image]

Comment: I've tried using complex exponential to integrate and have gotten an answer. I dont know if it is correct. But how do i express my answer in terms of trigonometric and/or hyperbolic functions?

Comment: I've attached a photo of the steps I've done so far

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicSine.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry

Comment: please, write whatever is in the photo using mathjax in the body of the question.

Comment: What do you mean by mathjax

Comment: @Jenny MathJax is a way of formatting maths on a computer. [Here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a quick tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Start with $\sin x=\Im e^{ix}.$ Then your integral is the imaginary part of the following integral:
$$\int e^{ix}\cdot\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}2\, dx=\frac 12 e^{ix}\cdot\left(\frac {e^x}{i+1}-\frac{e^{-x}}{i-1}\right)=\frac 12e^{ix}\cdot \frac{-(e^{-x}+e^x) + i(e^x-e^{-x})}{-2}=\\=\frac 12e^{ix}\cdot (\cosh x-i\sinh x).$$
As we are interested in the imaginary part, we can take use of the fact that $\Im ab=\Im a\cdot \Re b+\Re a\cdot \Im b$ and get the final result:
$$\frac 12\left(\sin x\cosh x-\cos x\sinh x\right)$$

It agrees with the [result from WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20sin%20x%20sinh%20x).

Disclaimer: I omitted $+C$ for clarity. Many people dislike it, so consider adding it.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a little confused. Isn't sin(x) = 1/2i (e^ix-e^-ix)?

Comment: It is! A bit more general result - Euler's formula - says that $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$. From this you can derive $\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ if you want, but this form is not needed in the above derivation.

Answer (score 0):

**Method I**

Using integration by parts twice,

\begin{align}
  I &=\int \sin ax \sinh bx \, dx \\
  &= \frac{\sin ax \cosh bx}{b}-\int \frac{\cosh bx}{b} d(\sin ax) \\
  &= \frac{\sin ax \cosh bx}{b}-\frac{a}{b} \int \cos ax \cosh bx \, dx \\
  &= \frac{\sin ax \cosh bx}{b}-\frac{a}{b}
     \left[
       \frac{\cos ax \sinh bx}{b}-\int \frac{\sinh bx}{b} d(\cos ax)
     \right] \\
  &= \frac{\sin ax \cosh bx}{b}-
     \frac{a\cos ax \sinh bx}{b^2}-
     \frac{a^2}{b^2} \int \sin ax \sinh bx \, dx \\
 I &=
 \frac{\sin ax \cosh bx}{b}-
 \frac{a\cos ax \sinh bx}{b^2}-\frac{a^2}{b^2}I+C \\
  I &= \frac{b\sin ax \cosh bx-a\cos ax \sinh bx}{a^2+b^2}+C
\end{align}

**Method II**

\begin{align}
  \cos (u+iv) &= \cos u \cosh v-i\sin u \sinh v \\
  \sin (u+iv) &= \sin u \cosh v+i\cos u \sinh v \\
  \int \cos [(a+ib)x] \, dx &=
  \int \cos ax \cosh bx \, dx-
  i\int \sin ax \sinh bx \, dx \\
  \frac{\sin [(a+ib)x]}{a+ib} &=
  \int \cos ax \cosh bx \, dx-i\int \sin ax \sinh bx \, dx \\
  \frac{(a-ib)(\sin ax \cosh bx+i\cos ax \sinh bx)}{a^2+b^2} &=
  \int \cos ax \cosh bx \, dx-i\int \sin ax \sinh bx \, dx
\end{align}

Equating the imaginary parts,

$$\fbox{$
\int \sin ax \sinh bx \, dx=
\frac{b\sin ax \cosh bx-a\cos ax \sinh bx}{a^2+b^2}+C
$}$$

**Method III**

By brute force,

\begin{align}
  & \quad \int \sin ax \sinh bx \, dx \\[10pt]
  &= \int
     \left[
       \frac{(e^{iax}-e^{-iax})(e^{bx}-e^{-bx})}{4i}
     \right] \, dx \\[10pt]
  &= \int
  \left[
    \frac{e^{(b+ia)x}+e^{-(b+ia)x}-e^{(b-ia)x}-e^{(-b+ia)x}}{4i}
  \right] \, dx \\[10pt]
  &= \frac{e^{(b+ia)x}-e^{-(b+ia)x}}{4i(b+ia)}
    +\frac{-e^{(b-ia)x}+e^{-(b-ia)x}}{4i(b-ia)} \\[10pt]
  &= \frac{e^{(b+ia)x}-e^{-(b+ia)x}}{4(-a+ib)}
    +\frac{-e^{(b-ia)x}+e^{-(b-ia)x}}{4(a+ib)} \\[10pt]
  &= \frac{(-a-ib)[e^{(b+ia)x}-e^{-(b+ia)x}]}{4(a^2+b^2)}
    +\frac{(a-ib)[-e^{(b-ia)x}+e^{-(b-ia)x}]}{4(a^2+b^2)} \\[10pt]
  &= \frac{bi}{4(a^2+b^2)}
      [-e^{(b+ia)x}+e^{-(b+ia)x}+e^{(b-ia)x}-e^{-(b-ia)x}] \\
  &  \quad +
     \frac{a}{4(a^2+b^2)}
      [-e^{(b+ia)x}+e^{-(b+ia)x}-e^{(b-ia)x}+e^{-(b-ia)x}] \\[10pt]
  &= \frac{bi}{4(a^2+b^2)}
     [e^{bx}(-e^{iax}+e^{-iax})+e^{-bx}(e^{-iax}-e^{iax})] \\
  &  \quad +
     \frac{a}{4(a^2+b^2)}
     [e^{bx}(-e^{iax}-e^{-iax})+e^{-bx}(e^{-iax}+e^{iax})] \\[10pt]
  &= \frac{b}{a^2+b^2} \times
     \frac{e^{bx}+e^{-bx}}{2} \times
     \frac{e^{iax}-e^{-iax}}{2i}-
     \frac{a}{a^2+b^2} \times
     \frac{e^{bx}-e^{-bx}}{2} \times
     \frac{e^{iax}+e^{-iax}}{2} \\[10pt]
  &= \frac{b\sin ax \cosh bx-a\cos ax \sinh bx}{a^2+b^2}
\end{align}

Comment: Integration by parts is one way to solve it as well however the question specifically states to use the complex exponential to integrate

Comment: Converting everything in terms of exponential function makes your life uneasy.  Anyways, there're $4$ terms involving $i$ instead.  Try to regroup and factor out common factors (e.g. $e^{x}$, $e^{ix}$, etc.) using law of indices.  My answer gives enough hint for regrouping.

Comment: I've tried doing that but I cant get the answer. Could you show me how to do it?

Comment: Please wait for it.  I'll come back soon.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: The answer is updated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be not the only way to proceed, but it is convenient to avoid working with $e^{(i \pm 1) x}$ terms too much. Don't be afraid by the amount of lines, I simply did almost all the steps.

$$I = \int \sin x \sinh x \ \mathrm{d}x =\\
\int \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i} \cdot \frac{e^{x} - e^{-x}}{2} \ \mathrm{d}x =\\
\frac{1}{4i} \int \left( e^{ix} e^x - e^{-ix}e^x - e^{ix}e^{-x} + e^{-ix}e^{-x} \right) \ \mathrm{d}x =\\
\frac{1}{4i} \int \left[ e^{(i + 1)x} - e^{(1 - i)x} - e^{(i - 1)x} + e^{-(i + 1)x} \right] \ \mathrm{d}x =\\
\frac{1}{4i} \int \left[ e^{(i + 1)x} - e^{-(i - 1)x} - e^{(i - 1)x} + e^{-(i + 1)x} \right] \ \mathrm{d}x =\\
\frac{1}{4i} \int \left[ e^{(i + 1)x} + e^{-(i + 1)x} - \left( e^{(i - 1)x} + e^{-(i - 1)x} \right) \right] \ \mathrm{d}x
$$

What can be recognized here is a hyperbolic cosine (**not** a trigonometric cosine, because it would be $\cos \alpha = (e^{i \alpha} + e^{-i \alpha})/2$ with $\alpha$ real: here, instead, the exponents contain complex quantities, $(i \pm 1)x$): simply applying the definition

$$\cosh z = \frac{e^{z} + e^{- z}}{2}$$

The integral becomes:

$$I = \frac{1}{4i} \int \left[ 2 \cosh \left[ (i + 1)x \right] - 2 \cosh \left[ (i - 1)x \right] \right]  \ \mathrm{d}x =\\
= \frac{1}{2i} \int \left[ \cosh \left[ (i + 1)x \right] - \cosh \left[ (i - 1)x \right] \right]  \ \mathrm{d}x =\\$$

Hyperbolic functions, like trigonometric functions, have sum and subtraction identities:

$$\sinh(\alpha + \beta) = \sinh \alpha \cosh \beta + \cosh \alpha \sinh \beta\\
\sinh(\alpha - \beta) = \sinh \alpha \cosh \beta - \cosh \alpha \sinh \beta\\
\cosh(\alpha + \beta) = \cosh \alpha \cosh \beta + \sinh \alpha \sinh \beta\\
\cosh(\alpha - \beta) = \cosh \alpha \cosh \beta - \sinh \alpha \sinh \beta$$

The integrand function is currently of the type $\cosh(\alpha + \beta) - \cosh(\alpha - \beta)$, whose value would be (by side-by-side subtraction of the above identities):

$$\cosh(\alpha + \beta) - \cosh(\alpha - \beta) = 2 \sinh \alpha \sinh \beta$$

But this would lead you back to the starting point. So, it is not convenient to use those identities now. It is convenient to directly integrate:

$$I = \frac{1}{2i} \left\{ \frac{\sinh \left[ (i + 1)x \right]}{i + 1} - \frac{\sinh \left[ (i - 1)x \right]}{i - 1} \right\} + C = \\
\frac{1}{2i} \left\{ \frac{i - 1}{i - 1} \frac{\sinh \left[ (i + 1)x \right]}{i + 1} - \frac{i + 1}{i + 1} \frac{\sinh \left[ (i - 1)x \right]}{i - 1} \right\} + C = \\
\frac{1}{2i} \left\{ \frac{i \sinh \left[ (i + 1)x \right] - \sinh \left[ (i + 1)x \right]}{-2} - \frac{i \sinh \left[ (i - 1)x \right] + \sinh \left[ (i - 1)x \right]}{-2} \right\} + C = \\
\frac{1}{4i} \left\{ \sinh \left[ (i + 1)x \right] - i \sinh \left[ (i + 1)x \right] + i \sinh \left[ (i - 1)x \right] + \sinh \left[ (i - 1)x \right] \right\} + C = \\
\left\{ \frac{\sinh \left[ (i + 1)x \right]}{4i} - \frac{ \sinh \left[ (i + 1)x \right] }{4} + \frac{ \sinh \left[ (i - 1)x \right] }{4} + \frac{ \sinh \left[ (i - 1)x \right] }{4i} \right\} + C = \\
\left\{ \frac{\sinh (ix + x) + \sinh (ix - x)}{4i} - \frac{ \sinh (ix + x) - \sinh (ix - x) }{4} \right\} + C = \\
$$

Now, the sum/subtraction identities for the hyperbolic sine

$$\sinh(\alpha + \beta) + \sinh(\alpha - \beta) = 2 \sinh \alpha \cosh \beta\\
\sinh(\alpha + \beta) - \sinh(\alpha - \beta) = 2 \cosh \alpha \sinh \beta$$

can be applied.

$$I = \frac{2 \sinh (ix) \cosh (x)}{4i} - \frac{2 \cosh (ix) \sinh (x)}{4} + C$$

Applying the definitions,

$$\sinh(ix) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2} = i \sin x$$

and

$$\cosh(ix) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2} = \cos x$$

So,

$$I = \frac{2 i \sin (x) \cosh (x)}{4i} - \frac{2 \cos (x) \sinh (x)}{4} + C =\\
\frac{1}{2} \left[ \sin (x) \cosh (x) - \cos (x) \sinh (x) \right] + C$$

which is the expected result.